# FUNCTION WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2 with NO_MESSAGES_UPDATE_1 = 'X'

Tags: abap, sap-erp

When using function module `WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2`, the delivery note is being printed even though we cleared the printer, copies and also the 'Print inmediately' check in tx NACE for message LD00 for a selected shipping point.

The configuration works for VL02N but it doesn't in our Z program where we manage some delivery notes.

This is the code:

```
  call function 'WS_DELIVERY_UPDATE_2'
    exporting
      vbkok_wa               = vbkok_wa
      commit                 = 'X'
      delivery               = lv_vbeln
      update_picking         = 'X'
      nicht_sperren_1        = 'Y'
      if_database_update_1   = '1'
      if_error_messages_send = ' '
    tables
      vbpok_tab              = vbpok_tab.
```

Ok, checking the import parameters of the function I can see `NO_MESSAGES_UPDATE_1` which, I can relate or imagine what could do but, has anybody tried this parameter?

Will this parameter avoid the printing of the message?

Comment: That function module is not released for use in customer code. Which means it isn't advisable to use it at all.

Comment: `which, I can relate or imagine what could do but, has anybody tried this parameter` why not just try and check if it does the job?

Comment: @Suncatcher Tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, tried the parameter `NO_MESSAGES_UPDATE_1` but didn't work.

We managed to literally delete the record in `NACE` for the shipping point and that made it.

Originally we just cleared the printer, the copies and the 'Print immediately' check.